# delete three level component(a component have an array of component, each have an array of compoent)

Tags: reactjs

I would appreciate it greatly if you could let me know how to deal with this problem.
I hava a page component which has an array of company component, and each company has an array of contract.
If I delete any company, every company component will re-render, so I cant put array of contract under each company state, so I put it under page component state.
The question is If I delete one company, how can I correctly re-render all contracts under each component.
Thank you for reading my problem, and sorry for my poor English:(
Error Message is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'contractList' of undefined"
My page code is...

```
class IRPage extends Component {
  // // initialize our state
  state = {
    companyList: [],
  };

  addCompanyArr = (newCompany) => {
    this.setState(
      state => {
        const list = state.companyList.push(newCompany);
        return {
          list,
        };
      }
    )
  };

  addContractArr = (index, newContract) => {
    this.setState(
      state => {
        const list = state.companyList[index].contractList.push(newContract);
        return {
          list,
        };
      }
    );
  }

  setCompanyArr = () => {
    this.setState(
      state => {
        const list = state.companyList;
        return {
          list,
        };
      }
    )
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container m-5">
        <IRContent companyList={this.state.companyList} setCompanyArr={this.setCompanyArr} addCompanyArr={this.addCompanyArr} addContractArr={this.addContractArr}></IRContent>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default IRPage;
```

My content code is ...

```
class IRContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    addCompany = () => {
      const companyNode = <IRCompany companyList={this.props.companyList} setCompanyArr={this.props.setCompanyArr} index={this.props.companyList.length} addContractArr={this.props.addContractArr}/>;
      const newCompany = {
        node: companyNode,
        contractList: [],
      };
      this.props.addCompanyArr(newCompany);
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <div className="container col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
            <h1 align="center">data</h1>
            <hr/>
            {
              this.props.companyList.map((element, index) => {
                return <div key={"myCompanyKey_"+index+"_"+this.props.companyList.length} id={index}>{element.node}</div>;
              })
            }
            <button color="primary" onClick = {this.addCompany}>
              add new company
            </button>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default IRContent;
```

My company code is...

```
class IRCompany extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    deleteCompany = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      var targetID = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("id")
      this.props.companyList.splice(targetID, 1);
      this.props.setCompanyArr();
    };

    addContract = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      var newContract = <IRContract/>;
      var targetID = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("id");
      this.props.addContractArr(targetID, newContract);
      this.forceUpdate();
    };

    render() {
        return(
          <div>
              {
                this.props.companyList[this.props.index].contractList.map((element, index) => {
                    return <React.Fragment key={"myContractKey" + index + "_" +this.props.companyList[this.props.index].contractList.length}>{element}</React.Fragment>;
                })
              }

              <button color="primary" onClick = {this.addContract}>主約</button>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default IRCompany;
```

I can successively add company and contract, but there are some problem on deleing.
Thank you for reading my problem, and sorry for my poor English:(

Comment: Would you be kind enough to show us a screenshot of an error message you're getting?

Comment: hello, thank you for reading, error message is TypeError: Cannot read property 'contractList' of undefined. I think the problem is Index which in addCompany, if i can  pass new props to child when I delete company, I guest I can fix this problem. Thank you again!

Comment: I think i see where the issue is coming from, the `<IRCompany />` is only rendered when the `addCompany()` is called. That's probably why the `companyList` is undefined

Comment: when i click add, everything is fine, only delete will be wrong